# Permutation of initialized states

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

Suppose I have an initial state: $$|A\rangle=\dfrac{1}{2^{3l/2}}\sum_{x=0}^{2^l-1}\sum_{y=0}^{2^l-1}\sum_{z=0}^{2^l-1} |x\rangle^{\otimes l}|y\rangle^{\otimes l}|z\rangle^{\otimes l}|0\rangle^{\otimes l}|0\rangle^{\otimes l}|0\rangle^{\otimes l}.$$

Now this state is an equal superposition of all states $\{0....2^l-1\}^3$.

Now I transform this state such that registers $|0\rangle^{\otimes l}|0\rangle^{\otimes l}|0\rangle^{\otimes l}$ contains all the states  $\{0....2^l-1\}^3$, but not in the traditional order i.e each state say $(|3\rangle  |7\rangle  |8\rangle)  |0\rangle   |0\rangle |0\rangle \to    (|3\rangle     |7\rangle     |8\rangle)|8\rangle|9\rangle|16\rangle$. If I keep doing this to all the initial states then I get all the states just in a permuted manner.

Also since the new permuted states are done obtained using a reversible transform I don't need the first three registers so I want to just make them $0$. Basically what I want is just the permutation of indexes for example I have $1,2,3,4$ then i want $4,1,3,2$. Consider without the $z$ state $$|A\rangle= (|0\rangle|0\rangle ) |0\rangle|0\rangle + (|0\rangle|1\rangle ) |0\rangle|0\rangle + (|1\rangle|0\rangle ) |0\rangle|0\rangle + (|1\rangle|1\rangle ) |0\rangle|0\rangle.$$

Now this state transforms into
$$|B\rangle= (|0\rangle|0\rangle ) |0\rangle|1\rangle + (|0\rangle|1\rangle ) |1\rangle|0\rangle + (|1\rangle|0\rangle ) |1\rangle|1\rangle + (|1\rangle|1\rangle ) |0\rangle|0\rangle.$$

The output state that I want is $$ |C\rangle= (|0\rangle|1\rangle ) |0\rangle|0\rangle + (|1\rangle|0\rangle ) |0\rangle|0\rangle + (|1\rangle|1\rangle ) |0\rangle|0\rangle + (|0\rangle|0\rangle ) |0\rangle|0\rangle$$

Edit: Classically I have three numbers say $x,y,z$ and I want to transform them to $(x'y'z')$ using a function $f$ that is invertible.

$$\begin{eqnarray}
   x'=f(x,y,z)\\
y'=f(x,y,z)\\
z'=f(x,y,z)
\end{eqnarray}$$

So my states $|x\rangle|y\rangle|z\rangle$ is the original and the result $x',y',z'$ is stored in the registers $|0\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle$.

Comment: So why use additionally registers? Why not just apply the permutation directly?

Comment: Sir the permutation is not a straightforward one as the permutation of the $x$ and $y$  state depends on the $z$ state and the permutation of the $z$ state depends on the $x$ and $y$

Comment: so while changing the states when i have say a particular state $|x\rangle |y\rangle |z\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle$ i change it to $|x\rangle |y\rangle |z\rangle|x'\rangle|y'\rangle|z'\rangle$ I cant modify the original registers since its value is necessary to modify the other registers

Answer (score 3):

To sum up, you have an unitary operation $P$ such that
$$
P \ \vert x \rangle \vert y \rangle \vert z \rangle \vert 0 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle \mapsto \vert x \rangle\vert y \rangle\vert z \rangle\vert 0 \oplus p_1(x, y, z) \rangle\vert 0 \oplus p_2(x, y, z) \rangle\vert  0 \oplus p_3(x, y, z) \rangle
$$
with $f$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ already implemented, invertible and you want to create a unitary operation $P'$ such that
$$
P' \ \vert x \rangle \vert y \rangle \vert z \rangle \vert 0 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle\mapsto\vert p_1(x, y, z) \rangle\vert p_2(x, y, z) \rangle\vert p_3(x, y, z) \rangle\vert 0 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle .
$$

This can be achieved easily by using the fact that the `XOR` ($\oplus$) operation is its self inverse and $S$, defined as the operation that swap the content of the registers given as input:
$$
S \vert x_1 \rangle\vert x_2 \rangle\vert x_3 \rangle\vert x_4 \rangle\vert x_5 \rangle\vert x_6 \rangle \mapsto \vert x_4 \rangle\vert x_5 \rangle\vert x_6 \rangle\vert x_1 \rangle\vert x_2 \rangle\vert x_3 \rangle.
$$
The $S$ operation can be implemented with `CNOT` gates.

The gate you are trying to implement is then given by $P' = P^\dagger S P$ (I'm not 100% sure that $P^\dagger$ implements the inverses of $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$, you may need to check that, if it's not the case then replace $P^\dagger$ by the unitary operation inverting $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$):

$$
\begin{split}
P^\dagger SP \ \vert x \rangle \vert y \rangle \vert z \rangle \vert 0 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle &= P^\dagger S \ \vert x \rangle\vert y \rangle\vert z \rangle\vert 0 \oplus p_1(x, y, z) \rangle\vert 0 \oplus p_2(x, y, z) \rangle\vert  0 \oplus p_3(x, y, z) \rangle \\
&= P^\dagger S \ \vert x \rangle\vert y \rangle\vert z \rangle\vert p_1(x, y, z) \rangle\vert p_2(x, y, z) \rangle\vert p_3(x, y, z) \rangle \\
&= P^\dagger \ \vert p_1(x, y, z) \rangle\vert p_2(x, y, z) \rangle\vert p_3(x, y, z) \rangle \vert x \rangle\vert y \rangle\vert z \rangle \\
&= \vert p_1(x, y, z) \rangle\vert p_2(x, y, z) \rangle\vert p_3(x, y, z) \rangle \vert x \oplus x \rangle\vert y \oplus y \rangle\vert z \oplus z \rangle \\
&= \vert p_1(x, y, z) \rangle\vert p_2(x, y, z) \rangle\vert p_3(x, y, z) \rangle\vert 0 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle 
\end{split}
$$

Comment: since $|A\rangle={2^{3l/2}}\sum_{x=0}^{2^l-1}\sum_{y=0}^{2^l-1}\sum_{z=0}^{2^l-1} |x\rangle^{\otimes l}|y\rangle^{\otimes l}|z\rangle^{\otimes l}|=H^{\otimes 3l}|0\rangle^{\otimes 3l}$ Then can i just appy $H^{\otimes 3l}$ to A to get back $|0\rangle^{\otimes 3l}$?

Comment: $H$ is its own inverse so yes, applying $HH$ to a qubit is the same as applying $H^\dagger H = I$ on this qubit. This reasoning can be applyied qubit-wise to your $3l$ qubits.

Comment: so instead of the XOR operation i define the operator say $\rho=I^{\otimes 3l}\otimes H^{\otimes 3l}$ after the swapping is done